# Throw weapons from behind shield wall

Tags: throwing-things, mythras, runequest-6

In Mythras "Breaking the Habit" scenario, there's an opponent armed with javelins hanging back behind the shield wall formed by other four enemies. His tactics are, according to the scenario:

> Harassing characters hanging back, pinning shields or providing close support to his friends against e.g. characters using Very Long reach weapons. If anyone threatens to break through the line, a readied javelin will be waiting for them.

At the start of the scenario the PCs are a few meters away of the shield wall. If the javelin thrower gains the initiative and wants to throw a javelin at one of the PCs... Are there rules addressing that case? I found rules to throw into a melee, but the PCs would not be engaged with the infantrymen forming the shield wall yet, so I guess it doesn't apply.

I guess it could be an attack roll with one or two steps of added difficulty, but I'd like to know if there's an specific rule that can be applied to this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific rule is the one you note "Firing into a crowd" p.108
*When firing at a specific target at the edge of a crowd or melee, the attack suffers a difficulty grade of at least Hard. If trying to fire through a group to hit a target in its midst, **or on the other side**, the penalty should be raised to Formidable.*

In this situation, it should be a Formidable penalty, even if they are unengaged, as I can't see the javelin infantry using anything other than a flat throw at that range - less than 5 metres!

From the scenario it is suggested that the javelin-thrower will attempt a missile attack in two situations:

**1) Unengaged PCs "hanging back" - this would include the archer at the back.**
I am not even sure if I would allow an attack without the Formidable penalty at the start as the feudal infantry troops are so tightly packed - 4 guys standing shoulder to shoulder across 3 metres is tight. Even targeting the archer would impose the penalty, so unless the archer is causing a lot of trouble I would hold off.

**2) One of the PCs breaks through the line.**
At this point, the PC will be free of the line and out of engagement. In this case, I would position the javelin infantry further back away from the line. If he keeps within 10 metres of the target he gets the benefit of being at "Close" range for a javelin - Javelin ranges are 10/20/50 (*Close Range – The distance over which Choose Location may be used as a non-critical special effect, provided the target is stationary or unaware of the impending attack p.62)* and he can be up to 20 metres away without penalty (distance penalties p.108)